# Android7でffmpegを実行するとエラーになります。

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Android用にビルドしたffmpegを実行しています。
Android6では正常に実行できますが、Android7だと以下のエラーが発生します。

```
01-10 16:21:16.120 534-534/? A/libc: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/XXXX/files/ffmpeg": /data/data/XXXX/files/ffmpeg: has text relocations
```

原因と解決方法がわからず苦慮しています。
アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記にて同じエラーがKnown Issueとして扱われているようです。
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/141

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android
からリンクされているビルド済みzipを使うことで解決した人がいるようです。

Comment: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android/releases の prebuilt-binaries.zip をダウンロードして実行してみたところエラーは発生しませんでした。 こちらを使用しようと思います。 ありがとうございました。